# Android Up Button to Kill Screen

Tags: android

It is easy for the "Up" button in Android to go back to the previous screen when there is only one screen that can open that activity, so defining its parent in the Manifest.

Is there an easy way to just kill an activity when the "Up" button is pressed?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for here. Are you trying to kill your app with the up button? Or just finish an activity that is part of your app?

Comment: whar do you mean by **Up** button?

Comment: @HamidShatu the up button is the arrow in the action bar

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Kill the activity not the application

Comment: The Up button DOES go back to previous activity and KILLS the current Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. e.g. :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, x.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This way all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the definition of the Activity in Manifest to "NoHistory" for the back stack.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.android.sample.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title"
    android:noHistory="true" >
</activity>
```